# Disable permalink on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

I have created a custom post type, but I do not want it to have a permalink. By default, after entering the post title, it creates a permalink. I do not need them to be generated.

From my reading, it is said that custom post type will have a permalink and there is no way of disabling it. Is there a way that I can prevent the ajax call that receives the permalink?

Comment: Do you want to hide the permalink under the post title on Edit Post page? Do I understand right?

Comment: yes, I can hide it with css, but I want to disable it so I dont have to use css. If i could disable the ajax  call it would be best

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
    add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html', 'my_hide_permalinks');
    function my_hide_permalinks($in){
        global $post;
        if($post->post_type == 'my_post_type')
            $out = preg_replace('~<div id="edit-slug-box".*</div>~Ui', '', $in);
        return $out;
    }
```

This will remove:

- Permalink itself
- View Post button
- Get Shortlink button

If you want to remove permalink only, replace the line containing `preg_replace` with

```
$out = preg_replace('~<span id="sample-permalink".*</span>~Ui', '', $in);
```

### UPDATE:

`get_sample_permalink_html` has changed in version 4.4.

Here is the updated and tested code:

```
add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html', 'my_hide_permalinks', 10, 5);

function my_hide_permalinks($return, $post_id, $new_title, $new_slug, $post)
{
    if($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {
        return '';
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me - but I had it return `''` and it did work. I don't know the implications of that though.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work.

Comment: That's strange, it worked for me before. Anyway, it has to be changed to meet WP 4.4 requirements. I've updated the code.

Comment: This answer seems to only hide the permalink from showing, but it is not fully disabled

Answer (score 7):

While the accepted answer seems to only hide the permalink from showing, but still being generated and accessible, you can disable the permalink from showing and being accessible by setting certain `register_post_types` parameters.

I've achieved what I needed by only setting the following, but depending on your specific case, you may want to adjust some of the [other parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

```
'public' => false,
'show_ui' => true
```

More: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108658/33056

Comment: In general, you are totally right, but the answer is given according to the OP's amendment commentary.

Comment: this answers the question perfectly. creating an extra function just to hide a permalink div is the utter definition of crazy

Answer (score 1):

As the [WordPress documention](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#public) suggests, simply turn off the `public` argument of the registered post type.

It will have the consequence to turn off the following arguments, only if not specified otherwise:

- exclude_from_search
- publicly_queryable
- show_in_nav_menus
- show_ui

So you will not get anymore the possibility to go on the singular and the permalink is not shown anymore on the admin and the "view" buttons are hidden too.

PS: The selected answer shows what should not be done when it comes to WordPress development, badly. There is no need to alterate the render of some HTML and/or code something since there is a **WordPress builtin Post Type API** for that.
So please consider my answer, as it meets all the question requirements and it is simple and straight to the point with a builtin solution.