# remove custom post type permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, filters, actions

I've registered post type with following --

```
$holidayLabels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Holidays'),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Holidays'),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Holidays'),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New Holiday'),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Holiday'),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Holiday'),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Holiday'),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Holidays'),
    'not_found' => __( 'No Holidays found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Holidays found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''

);

$holidayArgs = array(
    'labels'               => $holidayLabels,
    'public'               => true,
    'publicly_queryable'   => true,
    '_builtin'             => false,
    'show_ui'              => true,
    'query_var'            => true,
    'rewrite'              => array( "slug" => "holidays" ),
    'capability_type'      => 'post',
    'hierarchical'         => false,
    //'menu_position'        => 6,
    'supports'             => array( 'title'),
    'has_archive'          => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus'    => false,

);
register_post_type('holidays', $holidayArgs);
```

And I want to remove permalink that appears below title when I post new holiday or start editing existing one. 
[image]

I want to remove this because, holidays will be displayed in separate widget. I don't want admin to be able to see it as single post anyhow. There's no template defined for such.

Comment: Do you want them to have archive page and to be able to access them with permalink?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż no. that's why I want to remove permalink. There's no such page available. Holidays will be shown in widget itself and details with ajax in modal.

Comment: So you should also take care of disabling permalinks, archives, and so on. Take a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well, there is another way. And better, I guess.

You should look at [`register_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) parameters. You should probably set them like this:

```
'public' => false,  // it's not public, it shouldn't have it's own permalink, and so on
'publicly_queryable' => true,  // you should be able to query it
'show_ui' => true,  // you should be able to edit it in wp-admin
'exclude_from_search' => true,  // you should exclude it from search results
'show_in_nav_menus' => false,  // you shouldn't be able to add it to menus
'has_archive' => false,  // it shouldn't have archive page
'rewrite' => false,  // it shouldn't have rewrite rules
```

If post type is not public, then you won't see this part of editor.

Comment: Cheching the answer made by Krzysiek Dróżdż, Will this can be applied to custom taxonomies? PD: Sorry for posting this here, I don't have enough reputation to make a simple comment

Comment: This code does not work for me for WP v6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide this area by placing a small JavaScript code to `admin_footer` hook.

```
<?php
add_action('admin_footer', function() {
  global $post_type;
  if ($post_type == 'your_custom_post_type') {
    echo '<script> document.getElementById("edit-slug-box").outerHTML = ""; </script>';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one quick way would be to just hide the container div using CSS.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wpds_custom_admin_post_css');
function wpds_custom_admin_post_css() {

    global $post_type;

    if ($post_type == 'post_type') {
        echo "<style>#edit-slug-box {display:none;}</style>";
    }
}
```

Comment: that's surely one way to do this. But I was wondering for admin filter or something. But this does work and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this filter to achieve something similar:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sample_permalink_html/

> Returns the HTML of the sample permalink slug editor.

It seems effective. It's available as far as I can tell from WordPress 2.9.0 up.

Sample code:

```
add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html', 'my_sample_permalink_html', 10, 5);

function my_sample_permalink_html($html, $post_id, $new_title, $new_slug, $post) {
  return '<p>Custom HTML to replace the permalink editor.</p>';
}
```